# Add/update ACF fields with Woocommerce Rest API

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to update ACF fields via Woocommerce rest api and I can't make it work.

Here is what I have.

```
$data['acf']['acf_field1_name']=$acf_field1_value;
$data['acf']['acf_field2_name']=$acf_field2_value;
$data['acf']['acf_field3_name']=$acf_field3_value;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$ckey:$csecret");
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($curl);
```

Everything works, but the ACF fields don't get inserted or updated.
Changing data['acf'] to data['fields'] also does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: `To update your ACF field groups, you need to pass the data as a JSON encoded acf object`, so try `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data))`

Comment: Thank you @MosheGross. So I change curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data)); to curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data)); correct?

Comment: that seems right

Comment: @MosheGross It does not appear to work and returns status code 418. the data array contains many other standart elements for woocomomerce api like $data['stock_status']="outofstock"; etc. 

Should I run the json_encode just on acf fields? if so how? Thanks.

Comment: adding this ("Content-Type: application/json",) solved the 418 error, but ACF fieds still don't update. 

No matter what I tried like $data['acf']['acf_field_name']=$acf_field_value;  or  $data['fields']['acf_field_name']=$acf_field_value;  or  $data['acf_field_name']=$acf_field_value;  the acf fields still don't get added/updates.